# Making enumeration columns value into fields

Tags: mysql, go

I have a table that contains 3 fields:

`user_id`, `name`, `value`

There is no primary key in the table, the `user_id` can have duplicate values, For the `name` there are enumerated fields **age, job and salary.**

```
user_id |   name | value
------------------------
      1 |    age |    20
------------------------
      1 |    job |    IT
------------------------
      2 | salary | 20000
------------------------
      2 |    job |   Dev
------------------------
      2 |    age |    30
------------------------
```

I want to create a structure like below

```
user_id | age | job | salary
----------------------------
      1 |  20 |  IT |   NULL 
----------------------------
      2 |  30 | Dev |  20000
----------------------------
```

Main query :

```
 rows, err := db1.Query("select user_id from main_users");

 for rows.Next() {     
     rows.scan(&user_id)

     id := reflect.ValueOf(user_id)
     user_idvalue := id.Interface().(int)

     rows1, err1 := db1.Query("select age from users where user_id=$1", user_idvalue)
     rows2, err2 := db1.Query("select job from users where user_id=$1", user_idvalue)
     rows3, err3 := db1.Query("select salary from users where user_id=$1", user_idvalue)
 }
```

I am stuck at the part of with each result line the id compared for the 3 others queries and to be shown as one table.

Comment: The combination of the table schema with fields `user_id`, `name`, and `value` with the queries referencing fields like `age`, `job`, and `salary` is a bit confusing, is there a different table involved as well?

Answer (score 0):

First, the queries should look like this.

```
 userAgeValues, err1 := db1.Query("select value from users where user_id=$1 and name=\"age\";", user_idvalue)
 userJobValues, err2 := db1.Query("select value from users where user_id=$1 and name=\"job\"", user_idvalue)
 userSalaryValues, err3 := db1.Query("select value from users where user_id=$1 and name=\"salary\"", user_idvalue)
```

Then you have these values to do with what you want. Based on your description there should only be 1 row in each of these results.

Comment: i think mr @Frank that the UNION  solution  is for one field  selection here i have two collect different fields

Comment: I'm actually not sure that that's a requirement to use UNION, but I deleted that part anyways to avoid confusion.  I think the code above should work just fine for you, though.

Answer (score -1):

you can create a map with key= user_id and value = user struct

define a user struct and map :

```
type user struct{
    age    string
    salary string
    job    string
}
user := make(map[int]user)
```

get the whole data from the table and start loading it into your map

Comment: thanks @Jilan but this is  far away from what i am working on the problem as i explained is a getting data from a multiple query